# Google spreadsheet to Android app - data fail

Tags: android, google-sheets

I want to get Google spreadsheet data to my Android app.
I have looked for some example.
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android
This is a sample that I found. 
It can run, but when I change his spreadsheet to my spreadsheet.
It will fail.
I do not know what's wrong.

This is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIj08MUjTNZscHbKkbJJ2eNR1RYlhJLW7qDrcWRnJMM/edit?usp=sharing

This is my Code:

```
AsyncResult.java

    interface AsyncResult
    { void onResult(JSONObject object);
    }

DownloadWebpageTask.java

    public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    AsyncResult callback;

    public DownloadWebpageTask(AsyncResult callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to download the requested page.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // remove the unnecessary parts from the response and construct a JSON
        int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
        int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
        String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
        try {
            JSONObject table = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            callback.onResult(table);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {} 
        return sb.toString();
    }
    }
Team.java

     public class Team {
    private String position;

    public Team(String position)
    {
        this.setPosition(position);
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    }
TeamsAdapter.java


    public class TeamsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Team> {
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Team> teams;
    public TeamsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Team> 
    items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.teams = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.team, null);
        }
        Team o = teams.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView pos = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.position);
            pos.setText(String.valueOf(o.getPosition()));
        }
        return v;
    }
    }

mainactivity.java

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    ListView listview;
    Button btnDownload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            btnDownload.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btnDownload.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    public void buttonClickHandler(View view) {
        new DownloadWebpageTask(new AsyncResult() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
                processJson(object);
            }
        }).execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq? 
    key=1pIj08MUjTNZscHbKkbJJ2eNR1RYlhJLW7qDrcWRnJMM"); 
    }

    private void processJson(JSONObject object) {

        try {
            JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");
            for (int r = 0; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
                JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
                JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");
                String position = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
                Team team = new Team(position);
                teams.add(team);
            }
            final TeamsAdapter adapter = new TeamsAdapter(this, R.layout.team, 
    teams);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {}
     }
    }
```

Comment: See this https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq/use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-your-json-backend. You have to publish it to the web.

Comment: diogenesgg ,it still can not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the link you should be using

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pIj08MUjTNZscHbKkbJJ2eNR1RYlhJLW7qDrcWRnJMM/od6/public/values?alt=json